# why redirect (server-side) to root on nginx ingress (reverse proxy) & rewrite-target

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm using Kubernetes with Nginx ingress controller and I have two services (srv1 and srv2) on my namespace which I want to access them like this:

```
https://xyz.example.com/srv1/ => (point to the root of srv1)
https://xyz.example.com/srv2/ => (point to the root of srv2)
```

for example, if someone hit the below URL :

```
https://xyz.example.com/srv1/page1.aspx
```

then, they will hit the **page1.aspx** which is in the root of my application in **srv1**

it works just fine with the below ingress file:

**Problem:**

I have a second page which is **page2.aspx** and I placed it next to **page1.aspx**, so both of them are in root, now if I click on a button on the page1 which has a server-side code to redirect us to the **page2.aspx**, then I expected to get us into the below URL:

```
https://xyz.example.com/srv1/page2.aspx
```

but instead, it will redirect me to the below path:

```
https://xyz.example.com/page2.aspx
```

Just for clarification, I put an HTML link in the page1 which point to page2, it works just fine because it works in the client-side instead of the server-side.

so far I used the below 3 languages for the server-side redirection and all of them have the same behaviour:

```
C# & .net core (versions 2.1 , 2.2 , 3.0 and 3.1)
Python (version 3.7)
Ruby (version 2.7.1)
```

so I think the problem is from Kubernetes, anyone has any idea?

here are my ingress YAML:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ds1-ingress
  namespace: ds1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - xyz.example.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: xyz.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: srv1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /srv1/(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: srv2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /srv2/*
```

- Github's link for source-code:

https://github.com/POC-Vault/Routing

- Docker-hub' link for anyone who likes to pull the image and test it.

https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/farzadjalali/k8s-routing

- How to pull the docker image:

  docker push farzadjalali/k8s-routing:latest

Comment: I tested your ingress on my lab with similar setup as yours and for me your ingress is doing the right thing. How are you doing your HTML link? I used relative link: `<a href=page2.html>Go to Page 2</a>`.

Comment: Hi mWatney, Thanks for coming back to me, the client-side (HTML) is working just fine as I said it already in the above text (i.e. Just for clarification, I put an HTML link........), if you try to do a redirection in server-side then it won't work.

Comment: Ok, now I got what you are trying. Will try it on my lab and let you know.

Comment: Hi mWatney , I put a written a very simple website, and I  put it here: (https://github.com/POC-Vault/Routing), also I connect it to a DockerHub repo and you can download the docker image  like this:   docker pull farzadjalali/k8s-routing:latest

Comment: I tested your application and in my opinion you are looking to the wrong direction. As I mentioned in my previous comment, you have to use relative links in your application but you are using absolute paths. I changed the link from `/Home/Privacy` to `./Home/Privacy` or just `Home/Privacy` and it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply & the time that you spent, I do seriously appreciate it, I will check it out and come back again. - cheers :)

Comment: Have you managed to fix the issue?

Comment: I tested your suggestion It didn't work, (https://github.com/POC-Vault/Routing/blob/master/MyWebApp/MyWebApp/Controllers/HomeController.cs) , also I simplified everything because I thought maybe having HTML link on the page would confused people when I speak about server-side redirection.

Comment: this is as far as I can get on this. I'm pretty sure that your problem is not connected to your Ingress, as I said, it's working as designed. I would focus in the code.